# Prevent parent click being fired when dragging outside child editable element

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Let's say I have a `table` where each row have a `onClick` event.

Inside each row, one of the cell have an input.

```js
function handleRowClick() {
  console.log('click on row')
}

function handleCellClick(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log('click on cell')
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="handleRowClick(event)">
    <td>COLUMN 1</td>
    <td onclick="handleCellClick(event)">
      <input value="random string" />
    </td>    
    <td>COLUMN 3</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to prevent `handleRowClick` being fired when I'm dragging inside the input to select all the text if my mouse end on one of the adjacent cell?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag to signify if the mouse down occurred on the input element, and prevent processing in handleRowClick()

```js
        var flag;
var inp = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0];
var row = document.querySelectorAll("tr")[0];

inp.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  console.log("input mousedown");
  flag = true;
  e.stopPropagation();
});

row.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  flag = false; //in case the mouse was released on the body
});

function handleRowClick() {
  if (flag) {
    flag = false;
    return;
  }
  console.log('click on row');
}

function handleCellClick(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('click on cell');
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr onclick="handleRowClick(event)">
      <td>COLUMN 1</td>
      <td onclick="handleCellClick(event)">
        <input value="random string" />
      </td>
      <td>COLUMN 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```